# Mask sprite in circle with cocos2d 3

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, mask

Update of my question since I got further.

I am trying to mask a sprite with a circle, with the code below it seems to work.

```
    // Create the clipping node
    self.clippingNode = [CCClippingNode clippingNodeWithStencil:[CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"Home Scene/top-circle-mask.png"]];

    self.clippingNode.alphaThreshold = 0;

    // Add the image
    [self.clippingNode addChild:self.maskedImage];

    // And add the clipping node to the tree
    [self addChild:self.clippingNode];
```

I also had to add this to my AppDelegate:

```
[cocos2dSetup setObject:@GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES forKey:CCSetupDepthFormat];
```

However, the "first frame" renders the image unmasked, so that looks kinda ugly, how could I fix that? I have made a small video displaying the problem. http://cl.ly/U3QF

I am going for this look:

[image: Masked image]

Thanks

Comment: I believe the mask has to be an image (sprite) itself.

Comment: Yes, that does seem to be one of the problems, also I had to enable STENCIL, but now the first frame is still unmasked. How could I prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly set circle sprite with image in CCSprite. so you take view and add it into CCScene.

first of all you download [AGMedallionView](https://github.com/arturgrigor/AGMedallionView) class and add in to your project.

After import that class in your scene

```
#import "AGMedallionView.h"
```

in init method of scene

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]) )
    {
        AGMedallionView *view1 = [[AGMedallionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
        [view1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-Small@2x.png"]];
        view1.borderColor = [UIColor redColor];
        view1.borderWidth = 5.0;
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:view1];
    }
}
```

display as below

[image]

Comment: It's not 'Cocos way'.
I think, topic starter can use CCMask class.

Comment: Yes But you can integrated view with cocos2d.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your initial work, I was able to put a gradient on top of a scenery background like this:

```
CCSprite* spriteStencil = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:stringSceneryfilename];
spriteStencil.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
CCClippingNode* crop = [CCClippingNode clippingNodeWithStencil:spriteStencil];
crop.alphaThreshold = 0;
CCNodeGradient* nodegradient = [CCNodeGradient nodeWithColor:[CCColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0] fadingTo:[CCColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1] alongVector:ccp(0, 1)];
nodegradient.contentSizeInPoints = CGSizeMake(spriteScenery1.contentSizeInPoints.width, WINSIZE.height);
nodegradient.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
[crop addChild:nodegradient];
[spriteScenery1 addChild:crop];
```

The gradient only covers the scenery where the scenery file has alpha above 0. The scenery has a lot of fully transparent areas (the sky...) Note that I am using an adhoc created gradient (CCNodeGradient), so you don't need to use exactly a CCSprite that will be cropped. In my case it crops the gradient, then I put the gradient on top of the original image (this is the same image source as the stencil!)

Of course I also use

```
[cocos2dSetup setObject:@GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES forKey:CCSetupDepthFormat]; // for stencils to work? aka CCClippingNode
```

in app delegate.